# How to configure Threads in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to setup delay in `jmeter` each user Thread Group.

I am trying to run my script Thread group (users) 10,20,30 and 40 and having a  delay of 2 min each in them.

How to setup these things in `jmeter`?

Comment: Use a stepping Thread group.
Its really easy to setup. Just follow the following guide.
http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test your application with 10 users and each user will come after 2 minute delay than pass ramp up as 1200 sec in thread group

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best controller is "jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group". Why it's the best one is, If you use JMeter "Thread Group", we need to change the "Ramp-Up Period" depending on the Threads.

```
10 User, wee need "Ramp-Up Period" as 20 (1 users for 2 seconds =20/10) to meet you requirements .
20 user, wee need "Ramp-Up Period" as 40 (1 users for 2 seconds =40/20) to meet you requirements .
........etc
```

If you use "jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group" , we no need to change the "Ramp-Up Period" depending on Thread count. 
Just mention `"Next, add" :1 threads every 2 seconds`,"jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group" will take care Ramp-up irrespective of Thread Count.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stepping Thread to make your load testing, which helps you to simulate as an apllication used in real time

Answer (score 0):

Just add Constant Timer to your thread group. That's how it is described: "If you want to have each thread pause for the same amount of time between requests, use this timer.".

And if you want to reproduce a special case when you run 30 threads then make a break for 2 mins before next 40 users, then enable "Run thread groups consecutively" option in your test plan settings (top-level element) and add thread with only constant timer between them.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to test 40 uesr test with rampup of 10 users.
Each user will take 2 min to rampup. We can use following configuration.

[image]